Is there a function which satisfies these properties?
Dear Math Stack Exchange Community,
I am trying to find a function $f(r,t):\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ for a physics research problem, where I am trying to match different time dependent spacetime metrics at a special time dependent radius $r_s=r_s(t)$. The problem boils down to me needing a function $f$, which satisfies the following properties
1) $f\bigl(r_s(t),t\bigr)=0$
2) $\dfrac{\partial f(r,t)}{\partial r} \,\Bigg|_{\,r=r_s(t)}=1$
3) $\dfrac{\partial f(r,t)}{\partial t} \,\Bigg|_{\,r=r_s(t)}=0$
I have been trying all sorts of different ansätze, but there seems to be a general problem, hinting towards that a function with all these properties might not exist. For example, if I want to satisfy 1) by having $f=f(r-r_s)$, then
$\partial_r f=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial (r-r_s)}\,,$
$\partial_t f=-\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial (r-r_s)}\dot{r}_s\,,\qquad\dot{r}_s=\dfrac{\partial r_s}{\partial t}$
$\Rightarrow \partial_tf=-\dot{r}_s\partial_r f\,,$
which makes it impossible to satisfy 2) and 3) at the same time, as I do not want both derivatives to be zero at $r=r_s$. The function can therefore not solely depend on the argument $(r-r_s)$.
If anyone could tell me, whether a function with these properties exists (with an explicit example), or can provide a proof that it cannot, that would help me a lot.
Thank you very much.

Assume
1) $f\bigl(r_s(t),t\bigr)=0$
2) $\dfrac{\partial f(r,t)}{\partial r} \,\Bigg|_{\,r=r_s(t)}=1$
3) $\dfrac{\partial f(r,t)}{\partial t} \,\Bigg|_{\,r=r_s(t)}=0$

Then, due to the chain rule, we have for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
(f \circ (r_s \times \operatorname{id})) '(t)
& = & D(f \circ (r_s \times \operatorname{id}))\Bigg|_t \\
& = & Df\Bigg|_{(r_s(t), t)} \cdot D(r_s \times \operatorname{id})\Bigg|_t \\
& = & \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f(r, t)}{\partial r}\Bigg|_{(r_s(t), t)} & \frac{\partial f(r, t)}{\partial t}\Bigg|_{(r_s(t), t)} \\ \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} r_s'(t) \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
& \overset{\text{(2.) and (3.)}}{=} & \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} r_s'(t) \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
& = & r_s'(t) \\
\end{array}
$$
Since by assumption (1.), $f \circ (r_s \times \operatorname{id})$ is a constant function, we must have
$$
(f \circ (r_s \times \operatorname{id})) '(t) = 0
$$
But combining the two facts, we have:
$$
r_s'(t) = 0
$$
This shows that $r_s$ must be constant.

If I understand correctly, your first line is $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} f(r_s,t)$, which due to the chain rule becomes $\dfrac{\partial f(r_s,t)}{\partial r_s}\dfrac{\partial r_s}{\partial t}+\dfrac{\partial f(r_s,t)}{\partial t}$. Notice that in the first term the derivative is with respect to $r_s$, and not to $r$, as you suggested. This means that when using 1) and 3) we arrive at $\dfrac{\partial f(r_s,t)}{\partial r_s}\dot{r}s=0$, when evaluated at $r=r_s$, and can be satisfied by $\dfrac{\partial f(r_s,t)}{\partial r_s},\Bigg|{r=r_s}=0$, without enforcing $\dot{r}_s=0$.

@Daniel As far as I understand, the expressions $\frac{\partial f(r, t)}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial f(r_s, t)}{\partial r_s}$ denote precisely the same function.

@Daniel Also, the first expression ist just the derivative of the mapping $$\begin{array}{ccccc} f \circ (r_s \times \operatorname{id}) & : & \mathbb{R} & \to & \mathbb{R} \ & & t & \mapsto & f(r_s(t), t) \ \end{array}$$

I see it now, $\dfrac{\partial f(r,t)}{\partial r}$ being the same as $\dfrac{\partial f(r_s,t)}{\partial r_s}$ was a very subtle point, but the most important one, thank you! Such a function cannot exist then, unless $\dot{r}_s=0$.

Yes, you are right. You cannot satisfy all your conditions at the same time (unless $\dot r_s = 0$). This follows from differentiating (1) w.r.t.  $t$. Indeed, this implies
$$
\partial r f \cdot \dot r_s = \partial_t f$$
without any additional assumption on $f$.

I see your point, but strictly speaking, differentiating (1) with respect to $t$ gives $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r_s} \dot{r}_s = - \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}$, which would not automatically exclude 2) and 3) as $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r_s}$ can be different from $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r}$.
